# Reading a column from excel using shell script in Linux environment

Tags: linux, shell, rhel5

/need to read the 1st column and last of the excel file in ***linux*** environment.

Can some one help me with examples

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to export the excel sheet as a *CSV* then manipulate it using `awk` or similar, such as:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1, $NF}' file.csv
```

For example:

```
# cat test.csv
hello, goodbye, seeya
# awk -F"," '{print $1, $NF}' test.csv
hello  seeya
```

Edit - For info, "*$NF*" is Number of Fields, so essentially 'last field'.

Comment: Actually, I would recommend a tab-delimited file as that may help avoid the troubles with quotes.